# how to detect the end of (only) one file when merging SAS datasets

Tags: merge, sas, eof

## Question

To do something on the last *observation* in SAS, one can set an *end* -flag, e.g.

```
data myResult;
    merge myInput1 (in=in1) myInput2 (in=in2) end=last;
    by myKey;
    ** Do some stuff **;
    if last then ** Do special stuff **;
run;
```

But how do I react on only one of my inputs reaching the end?
`myInput1 (in=in1 end=end1)` does not work.

## Context

I want to compare the content of two large datasets and thus limit to 999 observations. If `myInput1` contains some extra observations in the middle, my program reports that, but also some lines from `myInput2` that were excluded by the `obs=999` clause in `myInput1`. I actually would like to write:

```
data diff_&memName.;  
    format problem $20.;  
    merge myInput1(in=in1 end=end1 obs=999) 
          myInput2(in=in2 end=end2 obs=999) 

    by moederartikelnr;
    select;
        when (end1 or end2) delete;
        when (not inFrom) problem = "only in 1_PROD";
        when (not inTo) problem = "only in 2_DVLP";
        when (not first.moederartikelnr or not last.moederartikelnr) 
             problem = 'duplicate key';
        otherwise delete;
    end;
run;
```

If you can help me in another way, please do so too.

Answer (score 1):

Given your context, I think it might be easier to just stop the DATA step after 1000 iterations.  On each iteration, one record is read from either dataset or both.  So after 999 iterations, 999 records will have been read (not necessarily 999 from both).  With this method, you do not need the OBS= option, so this will avoid false mis-matches.  Something like:

```
data diff_&memName.; 

    if _n_=1000 then stop;  *stop on 1000th iteration;

    format problem $20.;  
    merge myInput1(in=in1) 
          myInput2(in=in2) 
    ;
    by moederartikelnr;
    select;
        when (not in1) problem = "only in myinput2";
        when (not in2) problem = "only in myinput1";
        when (not first.moederartikelnr or not last.moederartikelnr) 
             problem = 'duplicate key';
        otherwise delete;
    end;
run;
```